# Unexpected error when arranging lists in data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have the following data...

```
mm1 <- c("A_01","S_1", 1, "S_2", 2, "S_3", 3)    
mm2 <- c("A_02","S_10", 10, "S_20", 20, "S_30", 30, "S_40",40)
MM <- list(mm1,mm2)
```

...that I need arranged in the following way:

```
  const   V2 V3
1  A_01  S_1  1
2  A_01  S_2  2
3  A_01  S_3  3
4  A_02 S_10 10
5  A_02 S_20 20
6  A_02 S_30 30
7  A_02 S_30 40
```

Note that the first element of each line of MM is a key, and the following elements are arranged in duplets. Thus, the following function provides the required transformation:

```
convert.res <- function (M){
  const <- M[1]
  M <- M[-1]
  tab <- matrix(M, nrow=2)
  tab <- data.frame(t(rbind(const,tab)))
}
```

So that `a <- convert.res(unlist(MM[1]))`correctly provides

```
  const  V2 V3
1  A_01 S_1  1
2  A_01 S_2  2
3  A_01 S_3  3
```

However, when applying to MM `b<-convert.res(unlist(MM))` it does not work:

```
Warning message:
In matrix(M, nrow = 2) :
  data length [13] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [2]
> b
  const   V2   V3
1  A_01  S_1    1
2  A_01  S_2    2
3  A_01  S_3    3
4  A_01 A_02 S_10
5  A_01   10 S_20
6  A_01   20 S_30
7  A_01   30  S_1
```

What is going on? Is there a smarter way to accomplish my objective?
Thank you all.

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(MM, function(x) cbind(x[1], matrix(x[-1], nc=2, byrow=TRUE))))`, or with your function `do.call(rbind, lapply(MM, convert.res) )`

Comment: Both ways solved the problem, thank you so much!